# Lesson 7: yarn hardhat deploy --tags mocks -> returns error (Full Blockchain Solidity Course 2022 - timestamp: 10:49.24)

Tags: javascript, solidity, chainlink, hardhat

`yarn hardhat deploy --tags mocks`

returns

`Error: expected 0 constructor arguments, got 2`

after running line

```
local detected! Deploying mocks...
An unexpected error occurred:
```

Checked my code several times but all seems identical to video lesson. Help plz!

Comment: _"Help plz!"_ - how? The error message clearly points to an error in your code but you've not posted any. See [mcve]

Comment: In some of your deploy scripts you pass arguments to constructor even though it doesn't take any. So look over the deploy script and in the args: [] don' specify any arguments. If you don't find the mistake just look over the github repo and check the code if it's identicall

Comment: Also, these types of questions are not for stack overflow. Either make an issue on the Github repo of the course or just try to follow the video.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by editing abi in the MockV3Aggregator.json file located in artefacts

artefacts > tests > MockV3Aggregator > MockV3Aggregator.json

```
  "abi": [
    {
      "type": "constructor",
      "payable": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "type": "uint8",
          "name": "decimals"
        },
        {
          "type": "int256",
          "name": "initialAnswer"
        }
      ]
    },
```